# the stroke width of the complete drawing changes

Tags: android

I have created a simple drawing app, in which i am using  a seek bar to get stroke width. But as soon as i change the stroke width, the width of complete drawing changes. Same happens when i change the pen color. How to individually assign stroke attributes to each path?
I have tried many answers but could not get the correct result.
I have tried storing the path and the respective `paint` associated with it and then drawing it. but that too didn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    View mView;
    private Paint mPaint;
    SeekBar mSeekbar;
    int penColor = Color.BLACK;
    int bgColor = Color.WHITE;
    int StrokeWidth = 12;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myDrawing);
        mView = new DrawingView(this);
        mSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);

        mSeekbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mSeekbar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        layout.addView(mView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((DrawingView) mView).init();
        penSize();


    }

    public void penSize() {
        mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                ((DrawingView) mView).changePenSize(StrokeWidth);
                StrokeWidth = i;

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                ((DrawingView) mView).changePenSize(StrokeWidth);


            }
        });    
    }


    class DrawingView extends View {

        private Path path;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;


        public DrawingView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            path = new Path();
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(820, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            this.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(penColor);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);    
        }

        public void changePenSize(int size) {
            StrokeWidth = size;
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);
            invalidate();
        }    

        public void init() {
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(penColor);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);
        }

        public void setBGColor(int color) {
            bgColor = color;
            this.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
            invalidate();    
        }

        public void ClearPath() {
            path.reset();
            bgColor = Color.WHITE;
            penColor = Color.BLACK;
            init();
            invalidate();
        }

        public void changePenColor() {
            mPaint.setColor(penColor);
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Drawings");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Date now = new Date();
        String fname = "image" + now.getDate() + now.getSeconds() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.clear) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            alert.setTitle("Do you really want to clear ?\nYou can save before clearing.");

            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ((DrawingView) mView).ClearPath();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

            alert.show();

            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.bgColor) {
            bgColor();

        } else if (id == R.id.penColor) {
            penColor();
        } else if (id == R.id.screenshot) {
            takeScreenshot();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void penColor() {

        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(MainActivity.this, Color.BLACK, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {


            @Override
            public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

                penColor = color;
                ((DrawingView) mView).changePenColor();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

            }
        });

        dialog.show();    
    }

    private void bgColor() {

        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(MainActivity.this, Color.BLACK, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {


            @Override
            public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

                bgColor = color;
                ((DrawingView) mView).setBGColor(bgColor);

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }


    private void takeScreenshot() {

        mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        String filename=  UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";

        String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                getContentResolver(), mView.getDrawingCache(),
                filename, "drawing");


        if (imgSaved != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Drawing saved to Gallery! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you please add ur activity_main xml.. I want to use the same

Comment: Dude please mark it correct answer if it works for u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DrawingView extends View {

    ArrayList<DrawingPath> paths;
    private DrawingPath drawingPath;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;


    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(820, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        this.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(penColor);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);


    }

    public void changePenSize(int size) {
        StrokeWidth = size;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);
    }


    public void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(penColor);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(StrokeWidth);

    }

    public void setBGColor(int color) {
        bgColor = color;
        this.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        invalidate();


    }

    public void ClearPath() {
        paths.clear();
        bgColor = Color.WHITE;
        penColor = Color.BLACK;
        init();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void changePenColor() {
        mPaint.setColor(penColor);
        invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawingPath = new DrawingPath(mPaint.getStrokeWidth());
                paths.add(drawingPath);
                drawingPath.path.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawingPath.path.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mCanvas.drawPath(drawingPath.path, mPaint);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (DrawingPath drawingPath : paths) {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(drawingPath.strokeWidth);
            canvas.drawPath(drawingPath.path, mPaint);
        }


    }


}

class DrawingPath {
    Path path;
    float strokeWidth;

    DrawingPath(float strokeWidth) {
        path = new Path();
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help. You can other properties like color,style, etc to DrawingPath model.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked. was struggling with it since so long.